# apache storm start error normclasspath = cygpath if sys.platform == 'cygwin' else identity

Tags: linux, centos, apache-storm

I'm trying to setup storm 0.9.2 in CentOS 5.8

before I install dependency
jzmq, zeromq 4.0.4

this is my error log

```
File "./storm", line 51
normclasspath = cygpath if sys.platform == 'cygwin' else identity
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: i try storm 0.9.1 is work!

Comment: It's not necessary to install zeromq since 0.9.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for my Redhat 6 install on Python 3.4. I changed the hashbang in the `/bin/storm` file from: `#!/usr/bin/python` to: `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Answer (score 0):

This is a python version issue. The storm file is a python script file. Seems storm updated the python version in 0.9.2.

Python 2.6 or higher could resolve this problem.

Comment: i install python 2.7 and reruning 0.9.2
but same error

Comment: make sure you are using python2.7. Type python -version to check the current python version. If it's not 2.7, you can sudo move python27 python.